# Best place to addHeaderView in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, header, adapter, android-fragments

I'm having some trouble setting up my custom header in my list.

I'm creating a ListFragment with a custom adapter.  I have the list working fine, but I'm trying to figure out where in the lifecycle of a Fragment to attach the header.

I know the header has to be added before you set your adapter.

I tried adding my header in onActivityCreated, but that gets called every time my Fragment comes back from the backstack, and since I also set my adapter in onActivityCreated, it fails.

I tried adding it in onCreate, but the view hierarchy isn't available at that stage of the lifecycle.

I tried adding it in onCreateView, but I couldn't cast the view returned from inflate to a ListView.  So I couldn't add my header to a vanilla View.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know if you have solved your problem but here is a solution that worked for me:

Do not call `ListFragment.setListAdapter()` in your `ListFragment.onCreate()`. Make sure you have a field variable that can hold the header view, maybe like:

```
View mheaderView;
```

Then in your `ListFragment.onCreateView()`, inflate the header View and assign it to your variable like so:

```
View list_root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);
// Get the list header - to be added later in the lifecycle
// during onActivityCreated()
mheaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
return list_root;
```

Finally, in your `ListFragment.onActivityCreated()`  you can now call `ListFragment.getListView().addHeaderView()`. Basically something like so:

```
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
if (mheaderView != null)  this.getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);
// Don't forget to now call setListAdapter()
this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I get a crash on screen flip, when it complains about assigning a header view to a list after I've called setListAdapter.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. in these two methods of my fragment

Comment: `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container,false); 
      View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
         ((TextView)tv).setText("Contacts");
  return v;
    }`

Comment: `public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);     
       
        this.setListAdapter(null);
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                 new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                 new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);   
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
   
    }`

Comment: What about inflating the header, adding and setListAdapter in onViewCreated?

Comment: For anyone having problems like Konklone and Naveen Chauhan: calling setListAdapter(null) in your onDestroyView should do the trick.

Answer (score 32):

This solution works with screen flipping:

In onActivityCreated():

```
getListView().addHeaderView(mHeaderView);
if (mMyAdapter == null) {
    mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), null);
}
setListAdapter(mMyAdapter);
```

And in onDestroyView()

```
setListAdapter(null);
```

Comment: Thanks this help my. And I think that this is bug in ListFragment is should handle this itself.

Comment: thanks, its important to point out to set the ListAdapter to null in *onDestroyView*

Comment: I had same issues and resolved after adding 'setListAdapter(null);' to onDestroyView()

Comment: after setListAdapter(null) in onDestroyView ... when I return to my fragment it only show the empty view however I set a new adapter to my listview !! .. any help ?

Answer (score 18):

My solution:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setListAdapter(null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(mHeader);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution.

Comment: onActivityCreated() seems to be the best place to set onScrollListener() also

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for handling footer/header in list view. I use it in retained fragment. Adapter is initialized in renderView() method. This method can be called how many times you need (e.g. for refresh data in view) and footer/header works fine. I tested this code on Android 2,3,4.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    renderView();
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();

    // free adapter
    setListAdapter(null);
}


private void renderView()
{
    // reference
    ListView listView = getListView();

    // adapter
    if(getListAdapter()==null)
    {
        // init adapter
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(...);
    }
    else
    {
        // refill adapter
        // this method assign array list object to adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()
        mAdapter.refill(...);
    }

    // add footer
    setListAdapter(null);
    if(listView.getFooterViewsCount()==0)
    {
        mFooterView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_footer, null);
        listView.addFooterView(mFooterView);
    }

    // set adapter
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As short solution that worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    View headerView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);

    ArrayAdapter<XY> mAdapter = createAdapter(); // create here your own adapter
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    setListAdapter(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the following solution in my class extending `ListFragment`:

1) You, in your class `onActivityCreated` check if your adapter (which is a class variable) is null, then instantiate it. Then, inflate the footer, for example like this:

```
View footerView = View.inflate
    (getActivity(), R.layout.list_footer_loader_view, null);
```

You do only have to do this once! The footerView and the adapter only has to be created once. I create both of these in my `onActivityCreated`

Now to the "hard part", set your fragment in your onCreate to like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

I like to do it in the `onCreate` because it's not relevant for the activity. Now with the `setRetainInstance(true)` your fragment will not be recreated after the activity is destroyed, an event such as a screen orientation.

Now after those rows add the footer like this:

```
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

And then connect the adapter to the list:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This should be done every time the activity dies, do this in `onActivityCreated`.

And one of the other important things you should generally think about when it's coming to fragments is that you don't create the fragment every time the activity's `onCreate` is called.

For example do this (if your **NOT** using the supportpackage):

```
MyFragment myFragment  = (MyFragment)
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if (myFragment == null) {
    myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            add(myFragment, tag).commit();
}
```

This will only create the fragment once, if the tag is unique for that fragment of course.

Comment: You shouldn't be forced to setRetainInstance(true). That's agnostic to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with header layout height, so I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372304/header-view-height-in-a-listview?answertab=votes#tab-top):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(null);//avoid problems with orientation changes
    header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_diario_header,getListView(),false);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);
    ArrayList<Notificacao> nots = new ArrayList<>();

    nots.add(new Notificacao("16/04/2015", "Test", "Erro"));
    setListAdapter(new DiarioAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_diario, nots));
}
```

Header is a instance of View and DiarioAdapter is a custom ArrayAdapter.

### UPDATE 1

If you have problems with duplicate listfragment, just change FragmentTransaction ADD for REPLACE.