# Cannot add header view to list - setAdapter has already been called

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

> **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.**

I got this crash, but It didn't always happen! Actually my test phones have no problem. below is my codes.

Constructor

```
public MyListView(Context context) {        
    super(context);

    adapter = new MytListAdapter(context);
    setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and I called 'addHeaderView' after getting data from server. so I tried calling addHeaderView before setAdapter and I using visibility of attribute of view. but even if i set the view gone, but it still has a space.

any idea to solve this?

Comment: Try my answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31181366/4489494 hope this will helpful to you..

Comment: Try my answer here at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31181366/4489494 hope this will helpful to you..

Comment: You can check my answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583961/cannot-add-header-view-to-list-setadapter-has-already-been-called/54529452#54529452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not call `setAdapter()` until after you have called `addHeaderView()`. In your case, that would mean not calling `addHeaderView()` or `setAdapter()` until "after getting data from server".

Or, do not use `addHeaderView()`, but instead modify the adapter to have an additional row, in the 0th position, after you have retrieved your server data, where the 0th position is your virtual "header".

Comment: I changed my question, so I tried another way, but it still has a space.

Comment: The reason for the crash is mentioned in android api documentation also. Please check the answer for more details :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583961/cannot-add-header-view-to-list-setadapter-has-already-been-called/54529452#54529452

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this problem by using LinearLayout in HeaderView.

I added LinearLayout to HeaderView and if I want to make header invisible, I set GONE to setVisibility method of LinearLayout.

It doesn't make IllegalStateException at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To explain in details, as per Android guidelines. When `addHeader/addFooter` introduced before **KITKAT** version, developer should **call setAdapter only after adding Header/Footer**. After release Kitkat means Android `Versions>=Kitkat` developers can call setAdapter anytime

ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)