# Cannot add footer view to listview on loading dynamic items in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am mostly working with listview loading or adding more dynamic data. I am using volley for loading data over network. My listview is in a fragment. So not in an activity. What I want to do is , while listview is loading new item, I want to show loading progress bar like in Facebook and Twitter.

So I tried added footer when loading data and removed footer view. But it is throwing error when I add footer view to listview on requesting data over network.

This is how I initialised loading view for listview footer in Fragment:

```
.
.
.
.
    private View loadingView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_list_fragment,container,false);
        loadingView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_loading,container,false);

.
.
.
.
```

This is how I bind data to list view and add footer view

```
private void updateListItems()
    {
        listView.addFooterView(loadingView);
        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.api_endpoint)+"podcast";
        final HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String queryString = "";
.
.
.
```

My app is working fine before I add footer view to listview to show loading progress. But I used that function, it is throwing errors.

This is the logcat

```
02-11 12:53:52.844 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-11 12:53:52.844 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-11 12:53:52.844 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa613a908)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:515)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1540)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-11 12:53:52.848 5338-5338/com.blog.waiyanhein.llks.llks E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: You Can hide and show the footer view. It is the easiest way.

Comment: What is the attribute for it ? When i used seperated view, something like progress bar, it cannot be seen when listview become excessive to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(ListView view, 
            int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(ListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        // threshold being indicator if bottom of list is hit
        if (firstVisibleItem = threshold) {
            load();
        }
    }
});

private void load() {

    list.addFooterView(loadingFooter);
}
```

Comment: When i used seperated view, something like progress bar, it cannot be seen when listview become excessive to screen size

Comment: I already explained in question . It is throwing errors when I use it. Please why ?

Answer (score 0):

In your **onCreate** call something like this :

```
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_fotter, mListView, false);
mListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Then when data is fetched update your footer;

Take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584837/1462770) answer is helpful too.

Comment: I am using fragment. So will it be in onCreateView please ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

using `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` instead of `fragment`, when I tried to add a footer to a `ListView`. This error occurred only on Android 4.3, Level 19. Using `fragment` instead of `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` adding a footer was ok. Without a footer the error did not happen.

I solved this issue by:

- In `onCreateView`: create the adapter and set the adapter on the `ListView`
- In `onViewCreated`: create the footer view and add it to the `ListView` -  `listView.addFooterView(footer);`