# section header in list fragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I would like to create section headers in list fragment but really i don't know how to achieve that.. Am new to fragment.. I googled this but i couldn't find anything to achieve section headers in list fragments.. I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704478/best-place-to-addheaderview-in-listfragment), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661975/listfragment-add-headerview-gives-java-lang-illegalstateexceptionalled) 
and my expected output is
 [image]. Help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reffered to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943802/how-to-draw-a-section-header-in-android-listview-just-like-the-ioss-uitableview

Comment: @umair.ali i would like to create section header in list fragment not in listview.

Comment: I think there would be no major difference in implementing header with list view or list fragment...you just need to deal with you adapter to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) that comes expanded by default and disabled to expand.

Or, you could still use a `ListView` and create a custom adapter. Depending of the current element in the list (category, or item) you will inflate appropriate layouts.
A search on google by "android listview with categories" revealed [this tutorial](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/) which addresses your question.

Comment: i created section header in listview. Now am trying to achieve the same in list fragment

Answer (score 0):

you should override `getViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` in your custom adapter. `getViewTypeCount` should return `2`, 1 for the normal view and 1 for the header view, and `getViewType`, should return 0 for the header section and 1 for the normal entry. You will get two null `convertView`.

Comment: can u give me some example so that i can understand better

Comment: take a look here: http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/