# Putting a Textview on top of a List Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-listfragment

How Can I add a textview on top of a  fragment. I'm using the following adapter to populate the listfragment and the xml file is each row in the list fragment. I need to add a textview ontop of listview which must be scrollable along with the list?

```
     public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    public TextView txtName;
    public TextView txtTitle;


    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Storage storage;
    FontManager fontManager;
    Typeface typeface;

    public Adapter(Context _context,Storage _storage) {
        context = _context;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.storage = _storage;

        fontManager = new FontManager(_context);
        typeface = fontManager.getTypeFace();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _storage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row3, null);

        txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        txtName.setTypeface(typeface);
        txtName.setText(storage.getName(position));

        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        txtTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        txtTitle.setText(storage.getTitle(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:id="@+id/ll1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListFragment:

```
    public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

    int number;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        number = getArguments().getInt(
                "num", 0);
        new SampleAsyncTask(this, getActivity(), number).execute();
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }
    }
}
```

Following code is used in AsyncTask class to populate the list fragment

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(context, storage);
listFragment.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: add the textview as a header to the listview

Comment: How can I do the same in list fragment?

Comment: use a fragment with listvew and add the textview as a header to listview.

Comment: check my post hope it helps

Comment: if you want the view to scroll you need to add the view as a header to listview. check the edited post

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704478/best-place-to-addheaderview-in-listfragment

Answer (score 7):

You can do as below or add a textview as a header to your listivew

Quoting from the docs

ListActivity(ListFragment is similar)  has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in onCreate()`. To do this, your own view MUST contain a`ListView` object with the id **"@android:id/list"** (or list if it's in code)

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <fragment android:name="com.example.listfragment.MyFragment"
            android:id="@+id/frag"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    String names[] ={"A","B","C"};
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag, container, false);
      TextView tv = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      tv.setText("My Header");
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));
      return myFragmentView;
     }
     @Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         // on click display the item in toast
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (String)l.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
}
```

list_frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

snap shot

[image]

Edit: if you want the textview to scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Before calling setListAdapter

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text, null);
  TextView textinlfated = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  ListView lv = getListView();
  textinlfated.setText("TextView scrolls");
  lv.addHeaderView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

change adapter's getView method and put a case on position and in case of 0, return your textview in other cases listview items.

Comment: I need the textview as a heading for the listfragment and I need to add the textview dynamically.

Comment: I've tried this but the text displayed is Textview. if (position == 0) {
   TextView tv = new TextView(context);
   tv.setText("Heading");
  } else { }

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in this case?
try wrapping that textview in relativelayout.