# Header View height in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working with a ListView that is part of an ListFragment. I want to add a header with a specific/custom height but it does not matter what I put in the height of the header view, always it has the same height. Is possible to modify the header view height of a ListView?

Below the code I use:

*header.xml*

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

*ListFragment*

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        TextView fakeHeader = (TextView)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        getListView().addHeaderView(fakeHeader);
    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you pass in `null` as the second parameter to `inflate()`, you are saying there is no parent associated with the view. This has the unfortunate side effect where any `layout_` attribute you use is ignored as `layout_` parameters affect how the parent lays out the child view rather than directly affect the child (like other views): [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/Hepj6KynZD5) godes into more details on `layout_` attributes.

You can use `inflate(R.layout.header, getListView(), false)` to pass in the ListView which will eventually the parent of your header view (note the false says to not add the view directly - `ListView` will do this automatically for you).

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake, your solution works like a charm :D, thank you so much! When I used _inflate(R.layout.header, getListView(), false)_ it started to work.

Comment: this is a *really* great answer, that's what you get when read the docs, folks! Shame on us